# Receiving data from python to java

Tags: java, python, multithreading, threadpool

I have JAVA SDK files to interact with a third party software.

My goal is to receive the data sampled by my RaspPi sensors online/live and pass it to this software.

The issue is that, I want to run the scripts individually (each sensor has it own python code file), because of different time cycle (sample,calc....) of everyone of the sensors.

the script are in form of:

1. Initialization of GPIO
2. Functions declarations
3. Var declaration
4. Infinite LOOP of sampling, calculating (by functions) & printing new line (the data) to screen - usually a floating number.

For now, as I understand, I need to start the python once at start of my java, by thread/process/sub-process.... while every time new line printed it supposed to parse to AtomicInteger. and that continue running on background.

Then on the Java I have another infinite loop that inside:

1."get" each one of the AtomicIntegers.
2."pass" it..
and again "get" -> "pass" (this loop while have one second cycle).

this is my first time asking a question, i hope i explained myself correctly :)
thanks in advance to all answers.

Gil